# Who are some of the well known female Esperanto activists today?

Tags: culture, movado

I was reading a discussion on Telegram about female Esperantists and names like Lydia Zamenhof were mentioned. Who are some the ones that are active contributors in the movement today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based, because "most important" is a criterion that different people will interpret differently.  Could you choose something more objectively answerable?  Like, "who was the last woman to win the Esperantist of the Year award?"

Comment: [Katalin Kováts](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katalin_Kov%C3%A1ts).
But I agree with [Nathaniel](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/145/who-are-the-most-important-female-esperanto-speakers-today#comment212_145). Another suggestion: "What women of the present time who gained most of Esperanto awards?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are seven important names that immediately come into my mind (ordered by how important I consider their current or very recent contributions to be):

- Katalin Kováts, the leader of edukado.net, a web platform for teachers of Esperanto with a lot of useful material. She invests an incredible amount of time and energy into edukado.net, without any significant financial recompensations.
- Veronika Poór, the young new General Director of UEA. She leads the head office of UEA, i.e. is the boss for about ten professional Esperantists.
- Anna Löwenstein, who is the author of two recent novels that were well received in Esperantujo, as well as the head of the section of the Akademio de Esperanto that checks the linguistic correctness of Esperanto course material. In the latter role she contributed a lot to the Esperanto courses on Duolingo.
- Ilona Koutny, a linguist that leads the interlinguistic studies at the University Adam Mickiewicz in Poznań.
- Barbara Pietrzak, a radio journalist who leads [Pola Retradio](http://pola-retradio.org/), a podcast with two high-quality episodes published each weak. Additionally, she was a member of the executive board of UEA until last month.
- Ruth (Margo) Kevess-Cohen, the most active member of the Esperanto Duolingo team.
- Maria Rosaria (Sara) Spanò, new member of the executive board of UEA, previously active in TEJO.

Comment: Erin Piateski is admin of the Lernu! forum; I don't know how well-known she is it the Esperanto community in general, but she is well known to Lernu! members, and there are a lot of us :-).